# Use neural network to predict coordinates

Tags: coordinates, neural-network, coordinate-systems

I have a dataset that has some values from different sources for a particular coordinate XY.

How can I transform these coordinates so I can train a neural network to predict the coordinates X and Y from similar data inputs?

I have 12 inputs in the network but how should I transform the output?

My coordinates range from 0 to 63 max so should I use 6 bits for X and 6 bits for Y so the output has 12 bits?

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 |    X    | |    Y    |
```

Comment: I think there's no single correct answer and that it depends on your problem. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Let me try to clarify: I have a particular data set with 8 different values that identify a location (coordinates). I want to train a neural network to correctly identify the location from the input data.